# EF returns same row twice from View

Tags: c#, .net, entity

I am selecting the rows from view using EF 4. It is a simple select operation from the view. The Storage Schema in edmx, generated by VS 2010 says it has multiple primary keys, which is fine. The condition that I am supplying is to check if the ProductId is same or not. The code is similar to the following:

```
var returnedResult=ctx.vw_MyProductList.Where(x=>x.ProductName.Equals(suppliedProductId, StringComparision.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToList();
```

There are two records in the view that matches the condition. It returns two records that is what I was expecting. But the thing is it is returning the same first record twice. Looks like Framework knew there are two records, but somewhere in the line it copies the first record to the next and returns.

I checked in the SQL profiler, copied it and executed in the SQL-Server Mgmt Studio and it is returning the rows correctly as expected.

It doesn't make any sense to me, unless I am doing something wrong. I deleted the .edmx and started over but didn't work. It is just a simple select statement against view.

Looks like EF treats statements against Views a bit differently, does it?

Comment: How the view and the query and the edmx looks like? do you want us to guess???

Comment: EF does not know anything about views. It treats views as a regular table, except perhaps prohibiting updates. In addition to gdoron's questions, what are the values of the two rows that appear in your view?

Comment: edmx is generated by the VS. There are two rows in the view that has this same productId. First row's "ContentType" field is "CD" another's is "CD-Template", which is not one of the primary keys listed in the edmx. The thing is EF returns two rows both with "CD" for "ContentType". I captured the script created by the EF from SQL-Profiler. If I run the script against Mgmt Studio. It returns the two records with "CD" and "CD-Template". Please let me know if you need more explation.

Comment: @SUpreti That doesn't answer the question of what the edmx looks like. The most likely answer based on the information you've given so far is that you've set the product ID as the primary key for the view, which would be wrong since the product ID is not unique, and EF then sees the same record (after all, if the primary key value is the same, how could any other field be different?) is returned twice.

Comment: That, by the way, is not a difference between how EF treats tables and views. You can misconfigure the primary key for tables too :)

Comment: @hvd,Well, I thought I solved it by adding one more field of one of the tables that the view is created from. Which happened to be unique throughout the view. Looks like the primary keys generated by VS from different tables was not enough for EF to distinguish between two records. Thank you for your help, though.